# making array with array() or []? - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

in evey tutorial they said you should make an array with "array()" but I realize that I can also make it with "[]" what are the difference?

array() :

```
$a = array("red","blue","green");
```

[] :

```
$a = ["red","blue","green"];
```

Comment: The differences are the versions of PHP. It's in the manual. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Although the duplicate talks about empty arrays - the principle (IMHO) is still the same.

Comment: @NigelRen They are basically the same, given the versions of PHP though. I added another dupe under the one you chose.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, that ought to cover all the bases :)